# How to print a binary tree structure onto console having each of its levels inside a seprate list?

Tags: c#, .net, tree, console

A binary tree structure is given in form of its levels `List<List<Node>>` of elements (one on the first row, two on the second, 4 on the third...) each element prints into a vector of ints `(1,20,3)`. How to print them onto the console in form of a tree?

I tried to do it with tabs and depth

```
        Func<int, string> offsetBetweenNodes = currentDepth => Enumerable
                               .Range(0, (depth - currentDepth))
                               .Aggregate("", (s, i) => s + "\t");
```

Yet it does not work correctly for any row below second...

Comment: Use recursion to make it easier (?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Can you use indentation to indicate how far down in the hieararchy the current node is? Else, could you provide a picture / mock-up of what you are trying to do?

Comment: This article may help you. I posed a question very similar to yours as a challenge to readers back in 2010 and they gave some interesting solutions. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/09/old-school-tree-display/

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the tree you're representing here is a complete binary tree?  A general binary tree does not have the property that it must have 4 nodes on the 3rd level.